# Blazor Server with AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 7 Extended IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I'm learning Blazor and need some help.

My Blazor Server project requires an extended IdentityUser.

I would like to access the **FirstName** property in the LoginDisplay.razor file which is shown below.

Most of the discussions I have found are too old or do not address my specific issue.

MyProjectUser

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyProject.Data;

public class MyProjectUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
}
```

MyProjectContext

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyProject.Data;

public class MyProjectContext : IdentityDbContext<MyProjectUser>
{
    public MyProjectContext(DbContextOptions<MyProjectContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

MyProject's Program.cs

```
using MyProject.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using MyProject.Areas.Identity;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyProjectContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'MyProjectContext' not found.");

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyProjectContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyProjectUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyProjectContext>();

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<MyProjectUser>>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapBlazorHub();
            app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great, database is updated etc.

I simply want to access the MyProjectUser's **FirstName** property here:

LoginDisplay.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, -->@context.User.Identity?.Name!</a>
            <form method="post" action="Identity/Account/Logout">
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
            </form>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

The LoginDisplay is used in MainLayout.razor

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using MyProject.Data;

@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@inject UserManager<MyProjectUser> UserManager;
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync

<PageTitle>MyProject</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>      
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <LoginDisplay />
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter) should give you the different possibilities to access it safely. Read more specifically the section about `HttpContext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to add custom properities in MyProjectUser class, and run below command.

```
PM> Add-Migration FirstName  -Context 'MyProjectContext'
PM> Update-Database  -Context 'MyProjectContext'
```

Then I navigate to the Data in DB, add my FirstName and LastName.

[image]

#### My Test Result

[image]

My **LoginDisplay.razor**

```
@using blazorfirstname.Areas.Identity.Data
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<MyProjectUser> userManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, @GetFirstNameAsync() !</a>
        <form method="post" action="Identity/Account/Logout">
            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
        </form>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
        <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


@code {
    private string firstName;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authenticationState = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(authenticationState.User);
        firstName = user?.FirstName;
    }

    private string GetFirstNameAsync()
    {
        return firstName ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

My **MyProjectUser.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace blazorfirstname.Areas.Identity.Data;

// Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the MyProjectUser class
public class MyProjectUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @TrevorBrooks You need to maintain the newly added fields yourself.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the registration and profile pages to include these new properties and it's working nicely.