# ASP.NET Core Web API, EF 7, scaffolding stored procedures is not creating working code for SQL Server model generated by EF Core Power Tools

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using

- VS2022, C#,
- EF Core 7, ASP.NET Core Web API
- SQL Server 2019

I followed EF Core Power Tools from Erik Jensen from his GitHub site

https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering-Quick-Start

My problem begins with scaffolding stored procedures. Scaffolding tables works great, they work as expected.

In VS 2022, I created a new project using the template "ASP.NET Core Web API"

Project is called `RitePartService_11`.

Target Framework is .NET 7.0 (Standard Term Support)

I selected to use Windows auth, and checked the "use controllers", "enable OpenAPI" checkboxes.

These are my Nuget packages I use:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

The project builds and runs the WeatherService controller

Then I right-click on the project, and run EF Core Power Tools v2.5.1429, using connection to the RitePart database, and using EF Core 7.

Settings

- Context : RitePartContext
- Entity Types Path : Models
- Generate : Entity Types & DbContext
- Checked : Pluralize, Customize using C# - T4 (EF7),
- Include connection string
- Save, Build and Run - runs Weather Service controller

In `Program.cs` I add

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RitePartContext>();
```

before the line

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

Then I right-click and "Add Controller" - API\API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework

Model class is `tblPart`, context is `RitePartContext`, and the controller's name is `TblPartsController`

Save, Build and Run - runs Weather Service controller

I can run `TblPartsController` and the `GET /api/TblParts/{id}` method successfully

In `TblPartsController` now I comment out the

```
  GET w/o and id
  PUT
  POST
  DELETE
```

and the `private bool TblPartExists(int id)` methods

Save, Build and Run - all OK as before

Right-click on `efpt.config.json` and keep properties as previously.

I click on "stored procedure" and add this one:

```
    usp_tblParts_Select
```

Click OK accepting other items as they were

Save, Build and Run - runs TblParts controller, the `GET /api/TblParts/{id}` runs successfully

EF Core Power Tools added in the `RitePartContextProcedures` which has a

```
public partial class RitePartContext
```

and a

```
public partial class RitePartContextProcedures
```

which contains

```
public virtual async Task<List<usp_tblParts_SelectResult>> usp_tblParts_SelectAsync()
```

Right-click on controllers, choose "Add controller":

- Model class usp_tblParts_SelectResult
- DBContext : RitePartContext
- Controller Name : usp_tblParts_SelectResultController

Save, Build and Run - I'm getting an error running the selected code generator

> Primary Key not found

`RitepartContextProcedures.cs`:

```
    OnModelCreatingGenereatedProcedures(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

I change `HasNoKey` to `HasKey(e => e.PartId)`. I remove to NULL view at the end...

Then I add the controller again, Save, Build and Run - run the tblParts controller `GET /api/TblParts/{id}` OK

Then I tried calling

```
GET /api/usp_tblParts_SelectResult/{id}
```

and it fails with error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'usp_tblParts_SelectResult'.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__208_0(Task`1 result)   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator,  CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at RItePartService_11.Controllers.usp_tblParts_SelectResultController.Getusp_tblParts_SelectResult(Int32 id) in C:\Data\Project\RitePart\toAngularService\RItePartService_11\RItePartService_11\Controllers\usp_tblParts_SelectResultController.cs:line 42
> at lambda_method162(Closure, Object)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>
> ClientConnectionId:181bea74-6908-4abb-a3b8-b549c229de1a
> Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16

It appears that the call is passing the class name to the `SqlClient`, not the name of the stored procedure.

Comment: I haven't seen you run `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` command in your statement. Could you kindly check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637097/7687666).

Comment: The comment above just want to check is the database is normal as expect. If the database is normal, I will check it later.